# How to draw text on video to show subtitle on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, overlay, subtitle

How to show subtitle above video with an overlay view on iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an overlay view using UILabel to show subtitle as below

```
//Overlay View
UILabel *lblOverlayView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lblOverlayView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 459, 320, 21);
lblOverlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
lblOverlayView.alpha = 0.3f;
lblOverlayView.text = @"Video Subtitle";
```

then you can add it as a subview to the view of MPMoviePlayerController to show a subtitle while playing the video.

```
[_mpMoviePlayerController.view addSubview:lblOverlayView];
```

here, _mpMoviePlayerController is an object of MPMoviePlayerController.
Hope this will help you to fulfill the requirements.

Comment: thanks,  at last I finally realized this function.   thanks Kapil Mandlik,  thanks internet,thanks everybody.

Comment: your code is working, but your CGRectMake(0, 459, 320, 21); will likely go off visible area of iPhone screen in landscape mode.

Answer (score 1):

Add a subview to the view showing the video and put it in front. 
This might help:

```
[myView bringSubviewToFront: subtitleView];
```